# Where to search for steam greenlight games in the steam launcher?

Tags: steam

Since steam removed greenlight, how i can search for those concept games in the steam launcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [still all there](https://steamcommunity.com/greenlight). Just make sure to click on the background, not the green button labelled "read more".

In the launcher itself go into the shop, and then click on "Steam Distribution" in the footer to get to the greenlight page.